# How many solutions exist for this equation?

Tags: combinatorics, systems-of-equations, combinations, binomial-coefficients

How many integer solutions exist for $N,n,L_1,\ldots,L_n,$ $U_1,\ldots,U_n,x_1,\ldots,x_n\in\mathbb N$
$$\sum_{i=1}^nx_i=N$$
and 
$$
\forall i: L_i\le x_i\le U_i
$$

### ?

---

A simpler version, without the $U_i$ parameters (or if $U_i\ge N$) is to use the [stars and bars formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)), which says that if $L=\sum_{i=1}^nL_i$ then
there are $N+n-L-1\choose n-1$ solutions.

What about the general version? (I'm interested in a closed-form solution if possible).

Thanks :).

Comment: You can still do the trick you did without the $U_i$ parameters to get rid of the $L_i$ parameters. But you won't get it all the way down to stars and bars, but it will reduce the problem to a simpler case where there are no lower bounds but there are still upper bounds.

Comment: Denote the number of solutions by $P_N(U_1,L_1,...U_n,L_n)$.

Then there is a generating function given by 
$$f(t)=\displaystyle\sum_{N=0}^{\infty}P_N(U_1,L_1,...U_n,L_n)t^N=(t^{L_1}+t^{L_1+1}+...+t^{U_1})(t^{L_2}+t^{L_2}+1+...+t^{U_2})…(t^{L_n}+...+t^{U_n})=\prod_{i=1}^nt^{L_i}\left(\frac{1-t^{U_i-L_i+1}}{1-t}\right)$$.

Then $P_N=\frac{1}{N!}\frac{\mathrm{d}^N}{\mathrm{d}t^N}f(0)$. 

This generating function won't help much with calculating $p_N$, but could give a few asymptotic results.

Answer (score 1):

For the general version. You should use the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

Let $A$ be the collection of all nonnegative integer solutions to the formula and $A_i$ be the collection of all nonnegative integer solutions where $x_i>U_i$.

For each $I\subseteq\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, we denote $$A_I=\begin{cases} \bigcap_{i\in I}{A_i}, & I\neq\emptyset; \\
A, & I=\emptyset.\end{cases}$$
Then
$$|A_\emptyset|=|A|=\binom{N-L+n-1}{n-1},$$
where $L=\sum_{i=1}^n{L_i}$.

Otherwise, for each $i\in I$, we have $x_i>U_i$. We then set $U_I=\sum_{i\in I}{(U_i+1)}$ and $L_I=\sum_{i\notin I}{L_i}$. Applying the same counting scheme, we have 
$$|A_I|=\binom{N-U_I-L_I+n-1}{n-1}.$$
In particular, if $N<U_I+L_I$, then $|A_I|=0$.

Finally, the number of integer solutions with $L_i\leq x_i\leq U_i$ is 
$$\sum_{I\subseteq\{1,\ldots,n\}}{(-1)^{|I|}|A_I|}=|A_\emptyset|-\sum_{i=1}^{n}{|A_i|}+\sum_{i<j}{|A_i\cap A_j|}-\cdots.$$

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if there's a closed-form for this quantity?

Comment: Generally there is no closed form for that, as far as I know.

Comment: Maybe summation over a polynomial number of quantities? I want to implement this, and such an expression is not evaluatable even for moderate $n$ values.

Comment: Perhaps generating function would help? But sorry I am not very familiar with that.